# Text not wrapping in ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The ListViewItems are getting their width from the TextBlock element. I want the ListViewItem to fit to the ListView. I have seen in other posts that making `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` will fix the issue, but my problem persists. The second TextBlock element in the ItemTemplate is set to `WrapWithOverflow`.

Sources:

http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/2016/03/21/c-how-to-make-a-panel-within-a-datatemplate-fill-the-entire-width-of-a-listview-or-itenscontrol-derivative/

Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXX.Views.XXXXView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource BlackBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <ListView Grid.Column="1"
                      x:Name="UniqueShortDescriptions" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding UniqueShortDescriptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUniqueShortDescriptions}"
                      cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged($this, $eventArgs)]">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Navy"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                Margin="3"
                                Padding="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Date}" 
                                           Foreground="Black"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           TextBlock.FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=LongDescription}" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShortExpenseDescription}" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"/>-->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Cost}" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Source}" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The sample code you base sets the first container elements HorizontalAlignment property to stretch, but your code sets the ListViewItem's HorizontalAlignment property. So, you may set main Border elements this property to "Stretch". I mostly use ListBox if I do not need columns and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the code you posted to work by simply disabling horizontal scrolling of the ListView.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
```

Comment: Yes I did the same thing after posting this question. I was convinced it was something more subtle. Thanks for your answer.